# CSS to format table header

Tags: html, css

I confess I downloaded this CCS for table layout online a few years ago, have come to do a new table and I am finding that the header row is very cramped and it's hard to see where one column ends and another begins. There are no left or right border in the header either.

HTML:

```
<table align="center" class="stats4"> 
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Received    </th>
        <th>Open</th>
        <th>Pending</th>
        <th>Closed</th>
        <th>Closed <= 5 Days</th>
        <th>Closed 6-14</th>
        <th>Closed 15-30</th>
        <th>Closed > 30</th>
        <th>Avg Days To Close</th>              
    </tr>
    <%Do While not RSClosedCallSummary.EOF %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= RSClosedCallSummary("strCategory") %></td>
        <td><%= RSClosedCallSummary("CallsReceived") %></td>
        <td><%= RSClosedCallSummary("CallsOpen") %></td>
        <td><%= RSClosedCallSummary("CallsPending") %></td>
        <td><%= RSClosedCallSummary("CallsClosed") %></td>
        <td><%= RSClosedCallSummary("ClosedWithin5Days") %></td>
        <td><%= RSClosedCallSummary("ClosedWithin14days") %></td>
        <td><%= RSClosedCallSummary("Closed15to30") %></td>
        <td><%= RSClosedCallSummary("ClosedGt30") %></td>
        <td><%= FormatNumber(RSClosedCallSummary("AvgDaysToClose"), 2) %></td>  
    </tr>
    <%RSClosedCallSummary.MoveNext 
    Loop
    %>
</table>
```

CSS :

```
/* Stats 4 table styles */


table.stats4 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #666;
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 7px;
}

table.stats4 td {
    background-color: #CCC;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px #fff solid;
}

table.stats4 td.hed {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    border: 2px #fff solid;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I thought about adding a "padding:" to the table.stats4 td.hed section in the CSS - but it has no impact. In fact, even if I comment out that whole section, the header remains unchanged.

I've looked online but all the examples use IDs, not classes. I cannot remember exactly how the connection between the three elements exists. I think..

The top one (table.stats4) applies to the whole table.
The middle one (table.stats4 td) presumably applies to every cell in the HTML that uses the  tag (to excudes the stuff in the header which uses ?)
The bottom one (table.stats4 td.hed) is a bit confusing because there is no HTML element called . I don't understand this labelling. should it read "table.stats4 th"? It's v strange if I comment it out, the header is unchanged.

The entire CSS file is below;

```
body {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: white;
}

/* Hyperlink styles */


a:link {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Normal 'solid' black border table */

table.standard { font-size: 14px  border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Table Style for displaying of statistics */

table.stats {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #666;
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    float: left
}

table.stats td {
    background-color: #CCC;
    color: #000;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px #fff solid;
}

table.stats td.hed {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 2px #fff solid;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Stats 2 table styles */


table.stats2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #666;
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px/*;
    float:left*/
}

table.stats2 td {
    background-color: #CCC;
    color: #000;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px #fff solid;
}

table.stats2 td.hed {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 2px #fff solid;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Stats 3 table styles */


table.stats3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #666;
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

table.stats3 td {
    background-color: #CCC;
    color: #000;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px #fff solid;
}

table.stats3 td.hed {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 2px #fff solid;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#table_container {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Stats 4 table styles */


table.stats4 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #666;
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 7px;
}

table.stats4 td {
    background-color: #CCC;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px #fff solid;
}

table.stats4 td.hed {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    border: 2px #fff solid;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: header columns should be accessed through `th` selector, `td.hed` would refer to a `td`tag with class `hed` , which I don't see in your document.

Comment: Neither is there any `th.hed`. Additionally, you may want to use the `thead` and `tbody` elements.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? This sounds like a request for improving the presentation somehow, without identifying the problem and showing attempts at solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
table.stats4 tr th {
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

It'll add border to the table headings.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:-

```
.stats4 th {
    color:red;
}
```

Text inside table head will display in red.